# SQL Query Distinct Inner Join Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a problem with the following SQL INNER JOIN statement. I'm probably missing something syntactically:

```
SELECT * from
(SELECT DISTINCT Name from Table.Names WHERE Haircolor='Red') uniquename
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM Table.Names) allnames
ON uniquenames.Name = allnames.Name;
```

I want all the names which have a Haircolor of "Red" but I don't want any duplicate names.

```
NAME        HAIRCOLOR       ADDRESS   PHONE       EMAIL
-----       ---------       -------  -----       -----
Joe         Red          123 Street  20768422    blah@example.com
Joe         Red         828 Street   703435422   blah4@example.com
Joe         Red         165 Street   10768422    blah3@example.com
Jamie       Blond       4655 Street  10568888    blah3@example.com
John        Brown       941 Street   40768422    blah5@example.com
Josephine   Red         634 Street   43444343    blah2@example.com
Josephine   Red         394 Street   43414343    blah7@example.com
```

The query should return:

```
NAME        HAIRCOLOR       ADDRESS   PHONE       EMAIL
-----       ---------       -------  -----       -----
Joe         Red          123 Street  20768422    blah@example.com
Josephine   Red         634 Street   43444343    blah2@example.com
```

Maybe it involves a GROUP BY?

Comment: I imagine that `Haircolor='Red` is supposed to be `Haircolor='Red'` (with a single-quote at the end)?

Comment: What problem are you seeing?

Comment: I just updated the question- I'm not getting the data I want. I'm getting back all the names, not just the ones with Haircolor of "Red"

Comment: So after the Haircolor filter, you want one arbitrary row from each group, grouped by name. Or you want the first/best row from each group, for some ordering rule that we don't know. Sounds like one of those `ROW_NUMBER()` jobs. Unless your dialect of SQL is something like mysql where there is no `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I'm using SQL Server. I don't care what entry I pick- it could be the first, just need 1 of them. How would I go about that?

Comment: Why would you want the name to be unique, but not the Address, Phone, and Email? If you have two people named Joe with Red hair but live at different addresses, would you want only one to show up?

Comment: @wilsjd I'm creating a set of test data off a large DB- I'm not looking for precision, just want an instance of each name which has a haircolor of "Red"

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly:

```
select * from
(SELECT DISTINCT Name from Names WHERE Haircolor='Red') uniquenames
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM Names) allnames
ON uniquenames.Name = allnames.Name
```

- it depends on what you actually want to see.

UPDATE: SQLFiddle for original answer [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc2e4/2).

However, a better answer (if using MySQL) might be:

```
select * from Names WHERE Haircolor='Red' group by Name
```

(Note that the specific row returned for each Name matching the hair colour is essentially random.)

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc2e4/3).

Further Update: For SQLServer, try:

```
with cte as
(select n.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by address) r
 from Names n WHERE Haircolor='Red')
select NAME, HAIRCOLOR, ADDRESS, PHONE, EMAIL 
from cte where r=1
```

- this will return the first row (by address, alphabetically) for each name - SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc2e44/4).

Comment: This looks right, but for some reason, the names returned include all haircolors. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Sc0rpio: My original answer should only have returned Red haircolors, but would have returned *all* matching rows for that haircolor. I have updated my answer with a second query that should match your updated requirements, if you are using MySQL; if you are using another RDBMS (Oracle, SQLServer, PostgreSQL etc.) please can you let us know which one?

Comment: That's correct, except it returns all instances of "Joe" and "Josephine." I only want one instance of each name found- I only want one "Joe" and one "Josephine," it matters not which. Any ideas? I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: @Sc0rpio: See the *Further Updated* section of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a `ROW_NUMBER` query. I can't test it right now, so there may be some bugs to work out. But to give you a general idea, it starts with a query like this:

```
select
  t.*,
  row_number() over (partition by name order by address) as rn
from
  table t
where
  haircolor = 'red'
```

That gives you a row for every redhead, with an added column `rn` that gives a sequential number within each group of rows with the same `name`.

Then to get the first one from each group, you just add an outer query to select the rows from the first query where `rn=1`.

```
select * from (
  select
    t.*,
    row_number() over (partition by name order by address) as rn
  from
    table t
  where
    haircolor = 'red'
)
where rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response- is there a way to do this without adding a column? I don't want the extra column.

Comment: Instead of selecting all columns, select the specific columns you want and exclude the rn column.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE haircolor = 'red' GROUP BY name ORDER BY email ASC/DESC
```

From the original post i see that you appear to be joining a table upon itself, i cannot see why you are doing this at all

There have been some comments/answers based upon your join and i think that might be confusing things here. You have very heavily over-complicated your query.

If you happened to have two tables, clients and clients features/services then i could understand why you would need a join. But for a single table you just don't need it.

#### Update based on comment

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, haircolor, address, phone, email FROM names WHERE haircolor = 'red'
```

If the return result doesnt matter then this should do what you need. each returned row should have a distinct "name" so you should only return two rows, i have not tested it but you can try it out.

Here is the fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc2e4/7

Comment: I see your point, but how would I only grab only one instance of each name? It doesn't matter which one I grab.

Comment: It would help to know how you are laying out the result set, that will give us a better idea of how best to perform your query, i know you have said you want just one of each but the use case might better assist in an answer.
--
The problem you have is the data you are pulling contains unique data in all but, name and haircolor. If you choose to query by hair colour you are going to get all results for that colour. in order to filter that down further to the required results you would have to add additional clauses to the WHERE statement to reduce the result set further.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE based on OP's comment**: if you want the name to only occur once, you'll need to have an aggregate clause on the other fields and group by the name.

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Address), MAX(PhoneNumber)--, MAX(YourDesiredColumnHere)
FROM Table.Names 
WHERE Name IN (
      SELECT Name 
      FROM Table.Names 
      WHERE Haircolor = 'RED')
GROUP BY 
    Name
```

Comment: This only returns the names, not with their associated columns.

Comment: You should add whatever columns you want then to the select statement. Name, Address, Phone, etc. I would suggest this approach, rather than *. With SELECT * you're at the mercy of anyone who changes the table description.

Comment: Note that the Address and PhoneNumber won't necessarily be from the same record, though they will be from the same user.

Comment: I completely agree with @MarkBannister. I mentioned this to OP in the comments and he said that this is okay since it is a test data set.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from this bit

```
Table.Names
```

which looks wrong, why can't you do this:

```
SELECT * from Table.Names WHERE Haircolor='Red'
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The query you have in the OP is a very roundabout way of saying

```
Select * From Names Where HairColor = 'Red'
```

Joining the distinct subquery back to the original table basically negates the distinct keyword.  Could you provide some more information about what you're looking for?  An example would be best.

Comment: The issue with this is that I only want the DISTINCT names and their corresponding columns. So I want * for all the rows associated with each distinct name that has a Haircolor of "Red"

Comment: @Sc0rpio it seems to me you're using the word "distinct" in a way that only you understand, which doesn't correspond to what it means in SQL. Need more explanation of what you think it means.

Comment: I'm looking to only grab 1 of each Name (with a Haircolor of "Red") and the row associated with each. Should I be using something else?

Comment: Based on your example above, yes you want to use a Group By clause.  The remaining question though is which address/phone/email do you want to see for red-haired Joe? You have 3 to choose from.

Comment: @RaySaltrelli It does not matter- the first instance would work.

Answer (score 0):

brother , try to removed ur curly bracket , i hope the query below able to solved ur enquiries

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name from Table.Names
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table.Names) allnames
ON uniquenames.Name = allnames.Name
WHERE Haircolor='Red
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't care about wish row you want, I would do something like that.

```
   SELECT tblName.* 
   FROM Table.Names as tblName
   INNER JOIN ( SELECT Name ,HairColor, MIN(Email)
                FROM Table.Names
                WHERE Haircolor='Red'
                GROUP BY Name ,HairColor) as tmp ON ( tmp.Email = tblName.Email)
```